# How to fix '438 - Object Doesn't Support Property or Method Error'

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have included an audit trail code to be called to 2 different forms in my access database. The code works fine for one of the forms but in the other form it produces a 438 error.

-The same parameter is used to call the code in both forms
-The debugger highlights this line : 'If Nz(ctl.Value) <> Nz(ctl.OldValue) Then
-I have attempted to comment out the code which calls the procedure and the problem appears to be with the parameter "SingleName"
-I have checked both the Control Source and Name for the textbox and both appear correct.

```
Sub AuditChanges(IDField As String, UserAction As String)
    On Error GoTo AuditChanges_Err
    Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim ctl As Control
    Dim datTimeCheck As Date
    Dim strUserID As String
    Set cnn = CurrentProject.Connection
    Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset
    rst.Open "SELECT * FROM TBL_AuditTrail", cnn, adOpenDynamic, 
adLockOptimistic
    datTimeCheck = Now()
    strUserID = Environ("USERNAME")
    Select Case UserAction
        Case "EDIT"
            For Each ctl In Screen.ActiveForm.Controls
                If ctl.Tag = "Audit" Then
                    If Nz(ctl.Value) <> Nz(ctl.OldValue) Then
                        With rst
                            .AddNew
                            ![DateTime] = datTimeCheck
                            ![UserName] = strUserID
                            ![FormName] = Screen.ActiveForm.Name
                            ![Action] = UserAction
                            ![RecordID] = 
Screen.ActiveForm.Controls(IDField).Value
                            ![FieldName] = ctl.ControlSource
                            ![OldValue] = ctl.OldValue
                            ![NewValue] = ctl.Value
                           .Update
                        End With
                    End If
                End If
           Next ctl
        Case Else
            With rst
               .AddNew
               ![DateTime] = datTimeCheck
               ![UserName] = strUserID
               ![FormName] = Screen.ActiveForm.Name
               ![Action] = UserAction
               ![RecordID] = Screen.ActiveForm.Controls(IDField).Value
                .Update
            End With
    End Select
AuditChanges_Exit:
    On Error Resume Next
    rst.Close
    cnn.Close
    Set rst = Nothing
    Set cnn = Nothing
    Exit Sub
AuditChanges_Err:
    MsgBox Err.Number & Err.Description
    Resume AuditChanges_Exit
End Sub





Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
If Me.NewRecord Then
        Call AuditChanges("SingleName", "NEW")
    Else
        Call AuditChanges("SingleName", "EDIT")
    End If
End Sub
```

The BeforeUpdate event of the form is supposed to call the procedure and send any changes, deletions or additions to TBL_AuditTrail. 
After the data is inputted and I attempt to save, the 438 error occurs. 
The information is still sent to the table (TBL_AuditTrail)

Comment: OK, which control is it dying on?  Is there something *different* about that control than the other controls?

Comment: I tried it on 2 controls, as there are more than one controls I require the audit tag on. Both are text boxes though. I tried comparing the properties to see if I could identify any differences but nothing stood out.

Answer (score 1):

An unbound control doesn't have an *OldValue* property. You could check for that:

```
If ctl.ControlSource <> "" Then
    ![OldValue].Value = ctl.OldValue
Else
    ' Skip unbound control.
End If
```

Comment: Tried this but unfortunately I'm still getting the error message

Comment: I have also tried the form in an older version of my database and the audit trail works there. I then tried importing the form and updating the controls (there were some changes to the names) and it isn't working. Then I tried adding the exact controls to another form, and it worked there, I then copied the controls to the form with issues but then i got the error. So, I am guessing that the problem isn't with the control but perhaps the query. Could this be it?

Comment: It isn't the query, created a dummy form from the same query and it worked

Comment: Remove the controls one by one until the error is gone. Then investigate the last control moved.

Comment: Thanks Gustav! That's exactly the thought I had, so I'm in the process of doing that. It appears to be a minimum of 2 controls that are impacting it . I will update the post when I find the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the three forms in question, I can only say that something is different on Screen.ActiveForm.Controls(IDField) field.  I would compare the properties of all three fields to see how the one that is failing is different.

Comment: Tried this, but nothing stood out

Comment: Could you post screenshots of the properties of one that works and the other that doesn't?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm unable to post screenshots. The site says I have to at least be a 10 for the images.

Comment: When you said "nothing stood out", does that mean there are differences that didn't seem significant or you didn't see any differences?

Comment: The properties of the form itself are slightly different as the problematic form has an additional event procedure. Where the controls are concerned the textbox of the problematic form has no event procedures but the one that works has 4 event procedures.